# Convert latitude and longitude in shapefile to different scale

Tags: r

I'm working with a shapefile where the latitude and longitude is large.

Here is it bounding box:

```
> utah_ed@bbox
                min       max
coords.x1  239109.1  671324.5
coords.x2 4101331.7 4651097.8
```

However, when getting a Utah map from ggmap, the longitude is between (-113, -110) and the latitude is between (39.5, 42.0).

How do I convert them into the same scale so I can plot over them?

Comment: You have data in projected coordinates, look for the PRJ file for the projection.. To convert to DD (geographic lat/lon) you can use many tools but that depends on what software you have, do you have any spatial software or API to work with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your coords.x1 and x2 are not "large" they're just another "units" (more complicated though), different from lat and long, think of a ruler with inches and centimeteres, you need to convert either of them to the other, with library(rgdal) with something like

```
    coords<-read.csv("D:/coords_utms.csv")
coordinates(coords)<-c("x","y")
coords_man<-SpatialPoints(coords, proj4string = CRS("++proj=utm +zone=14"))
longlat<-spTransform(coords_man,CRS("+proj=longlat"))
```

where the .csv file has your coordinates

Comment: Since the data should be in Utah, utm zone 12 should be the right UTM zone.

Comment: `CRS("++proj=utm +zone=14")` looks like it has too many plus signs in it.

Comment: could be in any of the Utah state planes too - http://epsg.io/?q=utah

Comment: @Meo you may mark it as answer if it worked